Incorrect launch of the Python debugger via VS Code
In VS Code, when running the Python Debugger in the console, an extra path to the interpreter is displayed "PS C:\Python Projects> ^C". This happens between repeated debugger runs, whereas when starting a new console, the path is indicated in only one line. Could you please advise if this should be the case, or have I perhaps broken something? The path in the Windows settings seems to be correctly specified.
I reinstalled VS Code along with the "code" and "vscode" folders, and also reinstalled Python itself.
The path is specified according to the instructions. There are also suspicions regarding the Powershell parameters, but I'm new and don't know how to work with them.
launch

path


when VSC creates the terminal it knows what the current directory is, the second time it wants to start Python you could have changed the current directory so VSC uses the full path to the files.

you state Incorrect launch, but the debugger does it job, so it is not incorrect

That doesn't mean it started incorrectly and your debugging was carried out successfully, it just had the extra cd command. This may be a bug, I've reported it in GitHub and you can get a reply there.   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python-debugger/issues/329

Thank you very much for your help, I will keep an eye on the information
